# How Do I Shift a Column Block Horizontally in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I’m pretty new at VS Code. I have version 1.79 on Windows 10.

I’m trying to shift a selected column block horizontally, but haven’t succeeded so far. To be clear, I am ***not*** trying to change indentation. The column block (comment text) already has code text to its left. I want to shift the column block to the ***right*** to align it with other comments.

Couldn’t find anything in VS Code keybindings about it. Apparently this question has been asked before, but none of the keystroke combinations I saw in other threads worked for me.

I Googled the topic, but all the Web sites’ instructions are either years (and versions) old, or they tell you how to ***select*** a column block, but not how to ***move*** one. I didn’t find the topic in Microsoft’s VS Code FAQ, either.

I *did* find one site that said that **Ctrl-Shift-Alt-Right** would move a selected column block to the right, but it didn’t do anything.

Would be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

This picture shows what I’m trying to shift:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multicursor editing and put the cursors at the start of the block that you currently have selected (I.e. before each of your `#` comment characters, and then just press tab or space to insert spacing). The way you have your selection set up in your screenshot, you can press the left arrow key to get to the state I was describing. See also the `editor.action.insertCursorAbove` (bound by default to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd>) and corresponding `editor.action.insertCursorBelow` keyboard shortcut command IDs (for the `Add Cursor Above` and `Add Cursor Below` commands in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)). Or use alt+click to insert/remove cursors at specific positions, or the various other controls specified in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_column-box-selection.